# Alternative to AdWordsApp.Report

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

There is a limitation where the following codes can only export 10,000 rows to google spreadsheet.

```
var report = AdWordsApp.report(
" SELECT Week, AccountDescriptiveName, CampaignName, AdGroupName, KeywordText, QualityScore" +
" FROM KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT " +
" WHERE " +
" Impressions > 0" +
" AND AdNetworkType1 = SEARCH" +
" DURING LAST_WEEK");
report.exportToSheet(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet());
```

Is there a way for me to work around this limitation?

Thank you!

Comment: This is a limitation of using the adwords scripts...it will not export more than 10,000 rows. https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/reference/adwordsapp/adwordsapp_report